# Trying to center a paragraph in a div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, center

I'm very new to bootstrap so there are a few things I do not under stand. For some reason, inside my div, my paragraph isn't centering. Am I doing it wrong?

I tried what you're supposed to do. (It's at the very bottom)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class=c ontainer-fluid p-0>
  <!-- Adding the First Child Header Bar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" class="logoimg">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button><br><br>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Closing the First Child Header Bar -->


  <!-- Starting second bar-->
  <div class="bg-light">
    <h1 class="text-center">my website</h1>
    <p1 class="text-center">my website!</p1>
  </div>
  <!-- Ending second bar-->
```

Comment: It sounds like you're using Bootstrap (vs. pure HTML/CSS).  Q: What kind of element is "p1"?  Did you mean `<p>`?  What happens if you try `<p class="text-center">`?

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Centering a paragraph in a div is different than centering text in a paragraph. Please revise to clarify which you mean.

Comment: Your opening div tag has problems. It's missing quotation marks.

Comment: Also, `p1` isn't a valid element type. **That's your actual problem as the browser doesn't know what it is. It's treated as an inline element, so centering isn't possible.**

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the text-align property with a value of center in your CSS.

```
div {
  text-align: center;
}
```